# GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/Public/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORTransport.h' file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, podfile

I didn't change my code at all, and all of a sudden I got this error. This is not a file I created, it is probably from one of the pods I have included in my podfile, but I really don't know how to resolve this error.

I checked the filepath for the GDTCORTransport.h file and it seems to be outside the public folder, but I am not sure if I should edit the code of the file the error message is in since the error is in GDTCORTransport file from Google...

Let me know if you would like to see the podfile or some code

please help!!

Answer (score 2):

This might be a problem with header files on the pods source code.
To see which file click the file with error and open it on Xcode.

What I did to fix my pods was I looked manually at the path of the

`GDTCORTransport.h` file and replace it with the direct file like

`#import "GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORTransport.h`

Note: You have to unlock pod lock header files to edit them

Comment: Thanks! I deintegrated the pod and reintegrated them and it seemed to work. This wierd error keeps coming back sometimes though so I figure it's a wierd glitch

Comment: Its not a permanent fix , you will have to do this every time you build if the bug in the pods is not fixed